# React - scrollIntoView only works with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My scroll is being placing on the right place only if I use setTimeout, without this it just stuck or go to any random place.

**This works**

```
async componentDidUpdate() {
  let element = document.getElementById(myId)
  if (element) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      element.scrollIntoView({block: "center"});    
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

- Even with "0" as a timer the scroll is not working properly.
- I don't have any other thing on my componentDidUpdate()

It should work, since componentDidUpdate just finish with all the changes right? Then why is the code founds the element it doesn't place in the right position?

It seems that is waiting for everything rendered and loaded to act correctly. Any idea?

Comment: Even when the element is found in the DOM, the browser is probably not done laying out and repaint. Perhaps try wrapping it in `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => ...)`? Also I'd strongly suggest using hooks instead of class components...

Comment: Can you try with `useRef` as mentioned here https://kbenbeneck.medium.com/using-scrollintoview-with-react-components-ba41df3ff12 ?

Comment: @doubleya I'm using class components, there would be a lot of things to update and change if I decide to go to functional components.

Comment: @Terry same result with window.requestAnimationFrame :(